# Find the Integrand from a definite integral

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods

Assume we have a $d$-dimensional random vector $X =(X_1, \ldots, X_d)$, and it follows elliptical distribution
$$
X\sim EC(\mu_d, \Sigma_d, g_d)
$$
where

- $\mu_d=(\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_d)$ is the mean vector;
- $\Sigma_d=\{\sigma_{ij}\}, i, j=1,\ldots,d$ is the covariance matrix;
- $g_d$ is the generator.

We know that the subvector $(X_1, X_2)$ also has elliptical distribution with

- mean vector $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$
- covariance matrix
  $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{11} &\sigma_{12} \\
    \sigma_{12} & \sigma_{22}
    \end{bmatrix}
    $$
- generator
  $$
    g_2(t) = \frac{\pi^{(d-2)/2}}{\Gamma((d-2)/2)}\int_0^\infty g_d(t+r^2)r^{d-3}dr
    $$

**Now the questions is : If I know the left side $g_2$, how can I find the right side $g_d$ by numerical inversion of the integral?**